# Find the true start end dates for customers that have multiple accounts in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a checking account table that contains columns `Cust_id` (customer id), `Open_Date` (start date), and `Closed_Date` (end date). There is one row for each account. A customer can open multiple accounts at any given point. I would like to know how long the person has been a customer.

eg 1:

```
CREATE TABLE [Cust]
(
    [Cust_id] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Open_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Closed_Date] [date] NULL
)

insert into [Cust] values ('a123', '10/01/2019', '10/15/2019')
insert into [Cust] values ('a123', '10/12/2019', '11/01/2019')
```

Ideally I would like to insert this into a table with just one row, that says this person has been a customer from 10/01/2019 to 11/01/2019. (as he opened his second account before he closed his previous one.

Similarly eg 2:

```
insert into [Cust] values ('b245', '07/01/2019', '09/15/2019')
insert into [Cust] values ('b245', '10/12/2019', '12/01/2019')
```

I would like to see 2 rows in this case- one that shows he was a customer from 07/01 to 09/15 and then again from 10/12 to 12/01.

Can you point me to the best way to get this?

Comment: Have you had a look at gaps and island problems? What have you tired?

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this as a gaps and islands problem. You want to group together groups of adjacents rows whose periods overlap.

Here is one way to solve it using `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()`. Everytime the open date is greater than the closed date of the previous record, a new group starts.

```
select 
    cust_id,
    min(open_date) open_date,
    max(closed_date) closed_date
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when not open_date <= lag_closed_date then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by cust_id order by open_date) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            lag(closed_date) over (partition by cust_id order by open_date) lag_closed_date
        from cust t
    ) t
) t
group by cust_id, grp
```

In **[this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=cd083c1c4c73e82c534682b605adaa57)** with your sample data, the query produces:

```
cust_id | open_date  | closed_date
:------ | :--------- | :----------
a123    | 2019-10-01 | 2019-11-01 
b245    | 2019-07-01 | 2019-09-15 
b245    | 2019-10-12 | 2019-12-01
```

Comment: This will work well for a linear account progression, but will fail with more complex timings. For example. Account A opens 2010 and never closes; Account B opens and closes in 2012; Account C opens and closes in 2014. Because your query only compares to the neighbors, the gap between B and C will cause a new group despite the oldest account (A) still being open.

Comment: @ChrisHep: yes, possibly. But I do not see such cases in the sample data that OP provided (although I would agree that 4 records cannot be considered a comprehensive dataset), hence this answer.

Comment: You make a great point, the solution I was working towards assumed more complicated data than was present in the post. I've mentioned in my answer that yours is preferable if the sample data was indicative of the expected complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this with recursion. While this is certainly very heavy, it should accommodate even the most complex account timings (assuming your data has such). However, if the sample data provided is as complex as you need to solve for, I highly recommend sticking with the solution provided above. It is much more concise and clear.

```
WITH x (cust_id, open_date, closed_date, lvl, grp) AS (
   SELECT cust_id, open_date, closed_date, 1, 1
     FROM (
             SELECT cust_id
                  , open_date
                  , closed_date
                  , row_number()
                    OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY closed_date DESC, open_date) AS rn
               FROM cust
          ) AS t
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
   SELECT cust_id, open_date, closed_date, lvl, grp
     FROM (
             SELECT c.cust_id
                  , c.open_date
                  , c.closed_date
                  , x.lvl + 1                                                              AS lvl
                  , x.grp + CASE WHEN c.closed_date < x.open_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END        AS grp
                  , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c.cust_id ORDER BY c.closed_date DESC) AS rn
               FROM cust c
                    JOIN x
                         ON x.cust_id = c.cust_id
                            AND c.open_date < x.open_date
          ) AS t
    WHERE t.rn = 1
     )
SELECT cust_id, min(open_date) AS first_open_date, max(closed_date) AS last_closed_date
  FROM x
 GROUP BY cust_id, grp
 ORDER BY cust_id, grp
```

I would also add the caveat that I don't run on SQL Server, so there could be syntax differences that I didn't account for. Hopefully they are minor, if present.

Comment: This solution [does work too](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4321d77a97931478858f5367a1591d64) - although recursion is a performance killer, this would accomodate more complex cases than showed in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that:

```
select distinct
  cust_id,
  (select min(Open_Date)
   from Cust as b
   where b.cust_id = a.cust_id and 
   a.Open_Date <= b.Closed_Date and
   a.Closed_Date >= b.Open_Date
  ),
  (select max(Closed_Date)
   from Cust as b
   where b.cust_id = a.cust_id and 
   a.Open_Date <= b.Closed_Date and
   a.Closed_Date >= b.Open_Date
  )
from Cust as a
```

so, for every row - you're selecting minimal and maximal dates from all overlapping ranges, later distinct filters out duplicates